# Prove for that $(1 + \frac{x}{p})^p < (1 + \frac{x}{q})^q$ [without Bernoulli inequality or integrals]

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, binomial-theorem

Prove for $x > 0$ and  $0 < p < q$ that $$(1 + \frac{x}{p})^p < (1 + \frac{x}{q})^q$$

I think that binomial theorem might be of use in this exercise, but I'm not sure. I haven't been able to prove this on my own. Could you give me a hand with this?

EDIT: I'm not supposed to use integrals or Bernoulli inequality.

Comment: For small x,p,q its reverse

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ integers? What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: I was assigned this as an exercise by my Calculus lecturer. Lately, we've been learning about some basic function series.
I have no idea if this should be about integers. If you believe it makes no sense for $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$, then fine.

Comment: A couple of ideas are being exposed in the two answers to the proposed duplicate, neither of which requires that $p,q$ be integers.  Note in the vein of the first answer, we can replace $x/p$ by $z$ and raise both sides of the inequality to the $1/p$ power, so it becomes $(1+z) \lt (1+z/r)^r$ where $r = q/p \gt 1$.  The second answer gets a weak inequality using the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean inequality, but it is well-known that equality hold only when the quantities being averaged are equal, so I think strict inequality (as asked in both problems) is just a step away.

Comment: Since you want to restrict the problem to *not* use certain things, it would be expeditious to give some ideas of an approach yourself to help identify methods (e.g. derivatives if not integrals) that can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\frac{q}{p}>1$, by using *Bernoulli's inequality*, we have
\begin{align}
1+\frac{x}{p}=1+\frac{q}{p}\cdot\frac{x}{q}<\left(1+\frac{x}{q}\right)^{\frac{q}{p}}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\left(1+\frac{x}{p}\right)^{p}
<
\left(1+\frac{x}{q}\right)^{q}.
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, now it seems quite easy. Thank you!

Comment: @Cachetejack you are welcome.:)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** This is equivalent to showing that the function $f(r) := \left(1 + \frac{x}{r}\right)^r$ is increasing. To compute the derivative, we need to take the logarithm, but since $\log$ is strictly increasing, it's anyway enough to show that $\log f$ is increasing, that is, that $\frac{d}{dr} \log f(r) > 0$. Computing gives
$$\frac{d}{dr} \log f(r) = \log \left(1 + \frac{x}{r}\right) - \frac{x}{r \left(1 + \frac{x}{r}\right)} .$$
So, (rewriting in terms of the new variable $u := 1 + \frac{x}{r} > 1$) we just need to show that $$\log u > \frac{u - 1}{u}$$ for $u > 1$.

> **Additional hint** One option is to rearrange this as $$u \log u - u + 1 > 0,$$ but we can recognize the l.h.s. as an antiderivative for $\log u$. After determining the appropriate constant we rewrite the desired inequality $$\int_1^u \log v \,dv > 0 ,$$ but the integrand is positive for $v > 1$, so the integral is positive for $u > 1$ as desired.

Comment: Could you possibly prove that without integrals? I'm not supposed to use them. :(

Comment: One can also use that $\log(1) = \frac{(1) - 1}{(1)}$ and that $\frac{d}{du}(\log u) = \frac{1}{u} > \frac{1}{u^2} = \frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{u - 1}{u}\right)$ for $u > 1$. Though, if you're not supposed to use integration, perhaps differentiation is disallowed, too. In any case, if certain elementary techniques are disallowed, you should mention them in the original question. (At any rate, Solumilkyu's solution is quite nice, and the proof of Bernoulli's Inequality is very easy, and in particular requires no calculus.)

Comment: Well, it's not that I've been told not to use something, but we haven't discussed integrals on my Calculus lectures yet and so I can't use them. I'm allowed to use derivatives, though.

Comment: Solumilkyu's solution is very nice, but then I think that this is not what i was supposed to do as we've proved Bernoulli's inequality on my Calculus only for integrals. I'm sorry, I couldn't write what I can use specifically because there's 100 pages of it.